# Converting grayscale png with transparency using PIL

Tags: python, png, transparency, python-imaging-library

PIL corrupt png images with transparency if i make them grayscale. Why?

Here's my code:

```
input = Image.open('input.png')
output = ImageOps.grayscale(input)
output.save('output.png', **input.info)
```

Input

[image: http://imgur.com/a/m50p6]

Output

[image: http://imgur.com/a/m50p6]

is there a way to fix that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `convert` method with luminance trick:

```
Image.open('input.png').convert('LA').save('output.png')
```

Comment: This didn't work for me.  The transparent background got converted to black, and sometimes white.  I'd like to find a way to do this where the transparent part stays transparent.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue as well.  The only solution I've been able to find is to convert to 'LA' and then back to 'RGBA'

Try:

`Image.open('input.png').convert('LA').convert('RGBA')`

I was attempting to display the resulting grayscale PNG with transparency on a tkinter canvas, but I think this method will probably also work for saving the output.